# Node.js process with a non-zero exit code

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

Currently, I'm trying to run my ionic3  App in Android Emulator but when 
I use this command  `ionic cordova run android`

I get this error :

```
(node:6236) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
-----------------
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
```

any help please

Comment: How much memory does your machine have?

Comment: currently 4 GB Ram